# Restoring of iPad using recovery mode fail due to 15 minutes timeout

Tags: itunes, ipad, password, software-update, restore

I forget a passcode for my iPad Air (model A1474). After several unsuccessfull attempts to enter the passcode, it become locked permanently and asked me to connect it to iTunes. When I connect it to computer, iTunes says "iTunes could not connect to the iPad “Ilya V. Schurov’s iPad” because it is locked with a passcode. You must enter your passcode on the iPad before it can be used with iTunes." And iPad still doesn't allow me to enter passcode. I also turned off "find my ipad" feature and cannot erase iPad with iCloud.

So I finally decided to use Recovery mode. I followed the [official instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263), entered the recovery mode and began the restore/update process. Unfortunately, to proceed, iTunes have to download iOS 10 which is about 2GB. It seems that Apple's servers are overloaded and iTunes says it will take about 24 hours to complete the download (or even more). However, as the documentation says,

> If the download takes more than 15 minutes and your device exits recovery mode, let the download finish, then repeat these steps.

Indeed, after 15 minutes iPad exits recovery mode and restarts. The download is then stopped.

It is obvious that the repeating of these step will not help. Any other ideas how to restore iPad in this case?

Comment: I've not tried from recovery, but for a normal update you get the choices, "Download & Install" & "Download only". Is it not giving you the choice?

Comment: No, there's no option "Download only".

Comment: Then I guess the trick will be to get the ipsw separately, drop it in the right folder, then try again - links here [real Apple links, just exposed rather than hidden] - http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-10-10.0.1-download-ipsw-links-for-final-version-released/

Comment: This sounds like a network related issue. Try downloading from another wifi. Starbucks is pretty fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This constantly happens to me and people I know.

1. Download the .ipsw file - links to *true Apple Software* are listed at https://ipsw.me
   <sup>[files hosted by Apple, the site simply makes the files findable, as Apple doesn't publish the locations]</sup>
2. Place the file in `~/Library/iTunes/iPad Software Updates` or `~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates` depending on device.
3. Launch iTunes & connect your device
   The ipsw ought to be discovered automatically.
4. Follow the on-screen instructions

ipsw.me has links to all iOS versions, however generally only the latest is still being signed by Apple & will therefore be the only one that works for a restore.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, it gives an option to update and restore but not just restore. 15 minutes isn't enough time for two updates. Press the "x" and it should come up an option to update and an option to restore, update first then do a separate restore!